# Pigeonhole principle - how many people to get 2 with the same initials

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> There are 800 seats in the cinema. How many seats needs to be occupied
>   in order to have at least 2 people with the same initials (first name
>   and last name) in the cinema?

I think it's a problem for the pigeonhole principle.  I know that there are 26 characters in the alphabet. How can I use the pigeonhole principle? I don't know how to start.

Thanks

Comment: How many possible initials are there?

Comment: @lulu 26*26 = 676.

Comment: You can ignore the first sentence in the problem (if you didn't figure that out already).

Comment: Ok, so we could fill $676$ seats without ever duplicating initials.  What about $677$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $26$ letters in the English alphabet. That means there are $26$ choices for the first initial, and $26$ choices for the second initial. As such there are 
$$
26\cdot 26=676
$$

possible initials a person could have. That means that, via the pigeonhole principle, we could only have $676$ people in a room with unique initials. Once we go over that number, we are guaranteed that two people must share initials